# RabbitVCS partial checkout

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-checkout, rabbitvcs

I would like to partial checkout my repository via **RabbitVCS**.

I tried with right-click options, but under "*Update to revision...*" there is no option *Recursively/Only this folder/Custom depth*... ect. like in *TortoiseSVN*.

I only know how to download entire repository or make my folder working copy (I see green icon), but it doesn't give me anything - I don't see any directories inside.

I can browse repository, but I want to make my own working copy from the part.

I also know that I can do a [partial checkout from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945/can-you-do-a-partial-checkout-with-subversio), but I want to know if I can do this with *RabbitVSC*.

Comment: I see that someone today upvote this question. Thanks :) Now I would definetly say that You (so and I) should throw the hell away SVN and begin to be interested in Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "official" answer right now is "no", as of [this feature request](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/74) on the RabbitVCS GitHub repo from 2014/15. Short summary:

> Q: Do you plan to implement that in a close future?
>
> A: Patches welcome to do this, but no plans on our part.
>   *(Issue closed)*

Answer (score 3):

I found a temporarily workaround in RabbitVCS, tested on Xubuntu 12.04, thunar files manager:

1. Checkout repository without checked "recursive" option.
2. Recapture path to file that interests You in folders structure.
3. Go to repo-browser.
4. Find file, right click on it and choose "copy to" and select right destination.

That's the way I found it useful, althought it's very inelegant.

I'm still waiting for better ideas :)