# Delete file from the working copy only but not from the repository

Tags: svn

Since I could not find the answer of the above question anywhere in the web, I come with the solution myself. It's a manual process but I couldn't find any other standard solution. So here it is:

Suppose you want to delete the file **test.txt** from directory **work**. Now if you delete test.txt forcefully by

> rm -rf test.txt

command then on the next svn up on the **work** dir (or any of its parent-directories), the file will be restored. So the trick is to delete it from **.svn/entries** file, as well. Thus the complete sequence of commands for deleting **test.txt** only from working copy is:

```
cd work
rm -rf test.txt
svn st     #it shows ! sign beside test.txt which means that 
       #in the next **svn up** it will be restored
chmod u+w .svn/entries
vi .svn/entries
#delete the lines associated with test.txt
#you need to delete the following 3 lines from .svn/entries
#test.txt
#file
#^L
svn st #it doesn't report test.txt anymore
```

Comment: That only works for the checkout you have. If you check this out again to another folder, that checkout will contain that file and the metadata associated with it.

Answer (score 8):

*lallafa* [reports](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/32812-how-to-remove-directory-from-working-copy?p=116427&viewfull=1#post116427) a good method, based on something called *sparse directories*:

```
svn update --set-depth exclude <folder-to-delete>
```

- nice
- easy
- works on files

not good if:

- I guess won't help you avoid checking out GBs of data you have (although you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50980/611007).)
- doesn't work on switched directories (may or may not with a little work, not tested)
- on large directories, not a very good idea. [od_m3](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/40462-svn-up-set-depth-exclude-taking-an-excessive-amount-of-time-to-complete) says that on a *190 GB* working copy, with `svn 1.6` this method tooks *1 hours*, but on `svn 1.7` it tooks more than *50 hours*. This was in 2011.

added from [source](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/sparse-directories-now-with-exclusion):

if you later want to use that directory again, you can do

```
svn update --set-depth=infinity <folder-to-delete>
```

I wish I knew how can I list directories already "excluded" this way, because `st` won't show them. :D

---

another method from [same source by someone called 'Mike5' (or jed/jeds)](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/32812-how-to-remove-directory-from-working-copy?s=71b2e5826e1ee2aa200b4e187ed2f426&p=88296&viewfull=1#post88296) that works on directories:

for every directory you want to avoid updating, do

```
svn switch --ignore-ancestry http://dummy/exists/but/empty_folder some_folder
```

- replace `some_folder` with the folder you want to ignore.
- also replace `http://dummy/exists/but/empty_folder` with an existing path in your repository which is an empty directory, will never be updated nor deleted - supposedly created and dedicated for this purpose.

By this, you will achieve:

- switched directories not updating any more in the working copy
- no changes to the actual repository

You will *not* achieve:

- anything on files
- the directory won't disappear/be deleted (from file listing)
- getting rid of initial checking out of these directories, unless you do a checkout for 'immediates' with `--depth`, first, do this, and then continue the checkout (not tested).
- I guess you cannot get rid of downloading GBs of data you already have (not tested).

It is also a good idea to use `svn propset svn:ignore "*" empty_folder` on the dedicated empty directory, so noone can commit anything to it.

Comment: Sparse directories are really good when comes to hide unused branches. I like to work with the whole working tree checked out.
The [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) says that you can see checkout depth of a directory using `svn info`. I can't see any way to get a list of excluded directories, though.

Comment: This does not work anymore for me. I have a checkout, I want to hide directories, the above method does not work. "svn up" will again check out everything, "svn st" will report the deleted files as missing.

Answer (score -5):

It should be as simple as:

```
svn delete test.txt
svn ci -m 'Delete test.txt.'
```

Comment: should this not delete from the *repository* also , the exact opposite of what op wants?

Comment: OP doesn't want to delete the file from the repository which is exactly what this command does.