# Get Subversion repository size

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

How can I find

1. Disk usage or size of my entire Subversion repository
2. Disk usage or size only for a particular branch on my repo. Eg ( https://mysvn/svn/myrepo/myfolder)

OS: Windows 2008 server

I have RDP access to the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total size of a SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384067/total-size-of-a-svn-repository)

Comment: @royalTS : Thanks for looking into it but I don't think so its duplicate as I'm looking also to get the size of individual branches. Kindly correct me if I've misunderstood anything.

Comment: please take a look at the second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394621/3809520) which proposes to use the `svn list -v` command to calculate the size of each file. The only difference between the "whole repository" and a "branch" would then be the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find out the size of the repositories by checking their size on disk on the server. For example, if your repositories are stored under `C:\Repositories`, check the overall size of this directory or check the size of individual repository `C:\Repositories\MyRepository`.

> Disk usage or size of my entire Subversion repository

Just check the size of the repositories on disk.

In case you use VisualSVN Server, try the [**Measure-SvnRepository**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Measure-SvnRepository) cmdlet. It will produce the following output:

```
Name                                Revisions                 Size           SizeOnDisk
----                                ---------                 ----           ----------
MyRepo                                    498             3,340 KB             4,529 KB
MyRepo2                                   479            21,313 KB            22,571 KB
MyRepo3                                   201             1,032 KB             2,226 KB
MyRepo5                                     2                71 KB                90 KB
```

You can also check the SVN repo size in the VisualSVN Server Manager console:

[image: VisualSVN Server Manager]

> Disk usage or size only for a particular branch on my repo. Eg (
>   https://mysvn/svn/myrepo/myfolder)

Normally, a new branch in the repository should take minimum of space (several kilobytes). A branch or tag in SVN is a [cheap copy](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/using/#svn.branchmerge.using.create.dia-1). When you create a branch or tag, Subversion doesn't actually duplicate any data. Therefore, the repository should not grow in size (unless you are going to commit new large content to it).

Instead of counting the "branch size", check the size of revisions on disk, e.g. under `C:\Repositories\MyRepository`. You can also view and examine the repository storage statistics with the **svnfsfs stats** tool. Here is an example:

```
svnfsfs stats C:\Repositories\MyRepository
```