# How do I limit PySVN checkout to a specific filetype?

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

Assuming a directory structure on an SVN server that looks similar to this:

```
/ mainfolder 
../ subfolder1
   -big-file1.xlm
   -small-file1.txt
../ subfolder2
   -big-file2.xlm
   -small-file2.txt
```

With a checkout function in a Python script that looks like this:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_get_login = svnlogin

try:
    client.checkout(svnurl()+"/mainfolder",
    './examples/pysvntest')
    print("done")   

except pysvn.ClientError as e:
    print("SVN Error occured: ", e)
```

How do I limit the function to only checkout `small-file`'s?
Could be by filetype, by file size (or another smart way)

Comment: You can use [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945/can-you-do-a-partial-checkout-with-subversion) to checkout individual directories.
I haven't tried checking out individual files, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, but the issue is the files are not specific to a specific folder/directory, the file I need and the file I don't need is in the same folder

Comment: What about getting the file paths you need to checkout, by using `ls` and then filter the results?

Comment: If you have the time, could you provide an example? I would appreciate it

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://gist.github.com/aamnony/eaf952242998508fc17930fc8f5de8e8#file-svn_spare_checkout-py).
However I hit a wall I can't solve - can't actually checkout the files themselves, only their containing directories (not included in the example). When trying to checkout a single file I get a `pysvn.ClientError` "refers to a file, not a directory".
If a WC is not explicitly needed, an `export` is an option

Comment: Thank you for the example, I appreciate it. A WC is not needed and the files will ideally be deleted after my program has read the contents. With your example in mind, could I replace checkout with export to archive my goal?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I tried it myself and it seems to work fine (I did see some misbehavior when using the `recurse` flag, so keep that in mind). 

Do note the parameter name differences between the methods and the building of the destination paths.

Comment: BTW, if you only need to read the content of the files, you can go on a different route by using `client.cat` which reads the file content into a string.

Comment: Excellent, I really appreciate it! 
If you post your answer as an answer to this question, I'll give you a "solved" checkmark and mark this as closed :-)

Comment: Glad to help out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the file paths you need to get, by using `client.ls()` (or `client.list()`) and then filter the results.
**Note** that you cannot checkout individual files, so you need to use `client.export()` or `client.cat()`.

The following code should give you a a place to start:

```
import pysvn

url = '...'
checkout_path = '...'
file_ext = '.txt'

client = pysvn.Client()
client.checkout(path=checkout_path, url=url, depth=pysvn.depth.empty)

files_and_dirs = client.ls(url_or_path=url)

for file_or_dir in files_and_dirs:
    if file_or_dir.kind == pysvn.node_kind.file and file_or_dir.name.endswith(file_ext):
        client.export(dest_path=checkout_path, src_url_or_path=file_or_dir.name)  # TODO: Export to the correct location. Can also use client.cat() here, to get the file content into a string
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm on my phone right now but I'll get this marked as soon as I'm home and tested it!

Comment: Update:
Overall this works with some modifications, as an example be aware `client.export` is not able to create folders so you must add some `os.mkdir` inbetween each iteration, assuming the folders are nested like mine. 

Also I found out `client.ls` is quite slow (it takes over 10 minutes in my case). Will look further into this as it works, but sadly much slower than expected. 

Thank you again